# Common structure of gem

Tags: ruby, rubygems, structure

As we all know, the common structure of rubygem assumes presence of `lib` directory. I noticed, that generally in this directory are two items: `gem_name.rb` and `gem_name/`  directory. The `gem_name/` directory hold main sources of project. It is heart of application. So, the question is about `gem_name.rb` file. What does it stand for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason it's structured like that is if you had files other than `gem_name.rb` in the `lib/` directory (say `another_file_name.rb`), you'd be liable to cause problems if there was a gem with the name `another_file_name` and someone did `require another_file_name` - it'd load your file, rather than the other gem's file.

If your code is small enough it can all fit into `gem_name.rb`, then put it there, otherwise put it into `gem_name/other_file_name.rb`.

Answer (score 1):

Typically that just requires everything from the `gem_name/` directory that's needed. It's used to keep all the `require`s in a central location and separate from the actual code

Comment: Take a look for https://github.com/wycats/thor/blob/master/lib/thor.rb
I see only one require.

Comment: *shrugs*. Doesn't mean it's the rule. The `gem_name.rb` file is what gets required, so it must require everything else. In that case they require `thor/base`, which then requires a lot more.